# Вызов функции srand в C

Tags: c

Есть такой вопрос. Допустим, в некой функции `f1` я сделал `srand(seed1)`, и затем сгенерировал (`rand()`) 1 псевдослучайное число. Затем я в другой функции `f2` сделал `srand(seed2)` и сгенерировал несколько (больше одного) псевдослучайных чисел. Если я теперь в функции `f1` сгенерирую псевдослучайное число, оно будет зависеть от `seed1` или `seed2` ?
Имеется в виду именно стандартный генератор из `<stdlib.h>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оно будет зависеть от seed2: внутреннее состояние генератора - глобальная переменная.

Comment: msvcr100.dll содержит реализацию с TLS, но тут, я думаю, поток один, раз не указано иного.